# Was I right to bid something other than one club with the following hand?

Tags: bridge, bidding

This was a Baron Barclay's problem.

Both vulnerable, I was sitting South after three passes with the following hand: (All x's are 6 or lower).
(s) AT7x (h) Kxx (d)9xx (c) AJX.

I elected to pass. I have 12 high card points but no five card suit. And my distribution is 4-3-3-3, so I deduct one point. I have one T, one 9, and one 7, but less than what was expected in intermediate cards (no 8s).

My second choice, with the "right" partner, would be 1 spade. Rule of 15, opposite a passed hand in third or fourth seat. Switch my hearts and spades and I would just pass; the other side is more likely to have spades.

But the answer given in the problem was one club. The two partners got to a precarious, but makeable 3 spade part score because partner had, (s) KJ8x (h) Qx (d) KT9 (c) T87x. Partner had his "quota" of 9 hcps, something extra in intermediate cards, and above all, four pretty good spades.

Was this a "lucky" result that I did well to shun? Was this a "natural" result of an opening one spade bid? Or should I follow Baron Barclay's supposedly expert line and bid one club?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not even particularly close - just open 1C.

In 4th seat the overriding consideration is the ability to make a plus score, and the use of [Pierson Points](https://www.bridgebum.com/pearson_points.php) to make that evaluation is widely regarded as the best (to date) means of assessing that prospect.

Here you have 12 HCP with 2.5 QT, well placed J and T, and another good spot card (albeit unsupported) in the Diamond suit. Additionally you have 4 Spades. The Pierson Count for your hand is therefore:

- 12 HCP
- 4 Spades

Total = 16.

Even with a deduction in terms of overall strength of 1 point for the 4333 distribution you clearly make the 15 PP cut-off and should open 1C. Unless you are playing 4-card Major system (such as Goren or ACOL) do not lie and open 1 Spade here. Your possession of 4 good Spades is a defensive as well as offensive value, and if partner holds 5 hearts you want to make it easy, not hard, for that suit to be introduced by partner - you cannot bid it over a Negative Double. If partner calls a Negative Double over a 2H overcall you will be delighted to rebid 2S and land in the 8-card Major fit.

If you want to "play games" on this hand: after a 1D overcall and a *negative double* by partner, just rebid 1H and pass partner's response.

;-)

But don't open 1S playing a 5-card major system.

The appropriate time to open this hand 1 Spade is in 3rd seat, not 4th. The goal of that call is to buy the contract in 2S or 3S and go down one (undoubled) for a smaller minus than opponents' part score. In 4th seat you are opening only if a plus looks to be in the cards, as a pass out is better still than a small minus.

---

I have always seen a description pf Pearson Points given as ***HCP*** + Spades - never as *total points* + Spades. In the absence of an analysis otherwise, take that at face value.

Comment: This exactly.  I’d be very irritated if my partner opened 1S with four there - especially when I held xx AQxxx xx Kxxx  or something  like that and we actually have a good part score or even a game possible.

Comment: So in a "restricted choice," you'd pass rather than bid one spade? But "one club" is better than either of the foregoing?

Comment: @TomAu: Don't abuse technical terms - there is no *restricted choice* here, just good bidding decisions and bad bidding decisions. So just open 1 Club and stop mucking around.

Comment: So the spade suit supports my bid of one "club?" Because if you switched my spades with my weaker heart or diamond suit I should pass, right?

Comment: @TomAu: No, not at all. In that case you have 15 PP instead of 16, which still calls for an opening of 1 Club. PP = HCP + Spades, **not** Total Points + Spades, as I pointed out above. Further, your 12 HCP with 2.5 QT and good supporting structures must be regarded as a **good 12**, resolving all tendency to make a really bad call.

Comment: OK, "good 12" Almost, but not quite 13. But clearly 12+ versus 12-.Thanks for your help.